# How do I scale multiple images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, parse-platform, getjson

I have this method that grabs an image before it's saved to a parse.com database and scales it down.

**Take a look at the code:**

```
var Image = require("parse-image"); // module
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Garments", function(request, response) {
      Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: request.object.get("image").url()
      }).then(function(response) {
        var image = new Image();
        return image.setData(response.buffer);

      }).then(function(image) {
        // Resize the image.
        return image.scale({
          width: 300,
          height: 450
        });

      }).then(function(image) {
        // Make sure it's a JPEG to save disk space and bandwidth.
        return image.setFormat("JPEG");

      }).then(function(image) {
        // Get the image data in a Buffer.
        return image.data();

      }).then(function(buffer) {
        // Save the image into a new file.
        var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
        var cropped = new Parse.File("image.jpg", { base64: base64 });
        return cropped.save();

      }).then(function(cropped) {
        // Attach the image file to the original object.
        request.object.set("image", cropped);

      }).then(function(result) {
        response.success();
      }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
      });
});
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to do above for 5 more images?

**I have 6 image columns altogether.**

image, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6

A row will never exist without the "image" column being populated. The other images are optional. So when scaling I need to go ahead and scale "image" and if image2, image3, image4, image5 and image6 don't exist don't throw any errors. If they do exist then scale them down too.

I'm sitting here scratching my head trying to come up with an efficient way to code this. I'd really appreciate if a javascript expert could come up with something.

I don't feel me repeating this code a few more times is efficient at all.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn most of that code into a function that returns the final promise and use `Parse.Promise.when()` to wait for an array of promises to finish, here's a bit to get you started:

```
var imagePromises = [];

var garment = request.object;

// you said "image" is always populated, so always add it
imagePromises.push(createImagePromise(garment, "image", garment.get("image").url()));

// now conditionally add the other promises, using a loop to further reduce repeated code
for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    var imageColumn = "image" + i;
    if (garment.get(imageColumn) && garment.get(imageColumn).url()) {
        imagePromises.push(createImagePromise(garment, imageColumn, garment.get(imageColumn).url()));
    }
}

// now we have all the promises, wait for them all to finish before we're done
Parse.Promise.when(imagePromises).then(function () {
    response.success();
}, function (error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

The only last part is to make the `createImagePromise()` function.

```
function createImagePromise(garment, imageColumn, url) {
    // we want to return the promise
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url
    }).then(function (response) {
        // ... etc ...
    }).then(function (cropped) {
        // Attach the image file to the original object.
        garment.set(imageColumn, cropped);
    });
}
```

NOTE:

There is a [limit](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource) to how long this is allowed to run, `beforeSave` only has **3 seconds** to run before it gets terminated, which might not be long enough to process 6 images.